Problem injecting org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocator with Jersey 3.x
We have a Java 17 application currently running in Wildfly 26 which we would like to update for a more recent version of Wildfly. This app uses Guice for DI and Jersey for REST services and therefore also the hk2-guice bridge. I am running into a problem injecting a ServiceLocator into our configuration class (which extends ResourceConfig) as we move from Jersey 2.36 to 3.x -- ServiceLocator is required by the bi-directional HK2-Guice bridge code.
There seems to be relatively little discussion on SO of Jersey 3.x issues - compared with 2.x anyway - so I am wondering if what we are trying to do is actually possible! The existing code looks like this:
import javax.inject.Inject;
import org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocator;
import ...

public class MyJerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    @Inject
    public MyJerseyConfig(ServiceLocator serviceLocator) {
        logger.info(() -> "Bootstrapping Jersey 2.x");

        //configure HK2 DI framework
        register(new MyHk2Config());

        //bridge HK2 and our Guice DI
        createBiDirectionalGuiceBridge(serviceLocator, getServletModules(...));
        ...

which I've changed to (no longer using web.xml)
import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import jakarta.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocator;
import org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.InjectionManager;
import ...

@ApplicationPath("/")
public class MyJerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    @Inject
    private InjectionManager injectionManager;

    public MyJerseyConfig() {
        logger.info(() -> "Bootstrapping Jersey 3.1.x");

        packages("...");

        ...

        ServiceLocator serviceLocator = injectionManager.getInstance(ServiceLocator.class);

        //configure HK2 DI framework
        register(new MyHk2Config());

        //bridge HK2 and our Guice DI
        createBiDirectionalGuiceBridge(serviceLocator, getServletModules(...));
        ...

but in every case 'injectionManager' is null. I've alse tried using InjectionManagerProvider, InjectionManagerFactory and whatever other related classes I could find, but same result:
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.InjectionManager.getInstance(java.lang.Class)" because "this.injectionManager" is null
For completeness here are the existing and new dependency versions.
            Existing    New
Java        17          17
Jersey/hk2  2.36        various 3.0.x and 3.1.x
Guice       5.1.0       7.0.0
Wildfly     26          33


I've got a lot of questions :) But I guess the first one is why use WildFly if you're not going to use the features from it, e.g. integrated REST and CDI?

The short answer here is that this application is very mature and predates Wildfly. There will inevitably come a time when a root and branch rewrite becomes necessary but we are hoping we're not at that point yet.

One other component that I accidentally omitted from the above table is org.glassfish.hk2/guice-bridge, sorry. Existing version is 2.5.0 and new is 3.1.1 if that is significant.

Do you have a jboss-deployment-structure.xml that excludes the jaxrs subsystem as well as weld?

Thanks for getting back, @James. Yes, we have a jboss-deployment-structure.xml though it looks effectively empty:
code










`code`
I do however recall that in an earlier deployment (Wildfly 8) we had to remove the pojo and weld extension modules in standalone.xml though this seemed unnecessary in Wildfly 26.
You'll need to remove the weld and jaxrs subsystems for sure if you want to use Guice and Jersey.
